# how to check the time constantly in android studio with multithreading

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm new to the issue of parallel processes and therefore I have some doubts. It turns out that I have a project which I want once the user logs in to the app,
start to constantly get the date and time (hh:mm:ss) and pass this data continuously to another fragment. All this as long as the user can perform other actions in the app, can someone help me with this?
i used API 32

Comment: "start to constantly get the date and time (hh:mm:ss) and pass this data continuously to another fragment" -- what are you doing with the date and time that you need this data "continuously"?

Comment: In summary, it is a discussion app, when a user creates a new discussion, he must set the date and time of the end of the discussion 
So, as I mentioned before, my idea was that the user would log in to the app and while he was using the application in the background, he would be sending the fragment that contains the date and time of closing the debate, so that it is continually being compared if the current time is equal to the one defined for the closing of the debate, if so, then the debate is deleted

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to get an event when it is time to close the debate? What is the value in constantly burning the CPU and draining the battery for "continually being compared if the current time is equal to the one defined for the closing of the debate"?

Comment: esque is not just a debate, there can be debates and you should keep asking constantly while the app is in use

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, I think what you need is to calculate the time passed by using `System.getTimeInMillis()`. E.g.

```
// you save the last time user did something he/she can do
// I'm using sharedPreferences as an example, you can save it in any way you want
// depending on the scope you need
val lastTimeUserDidSmthInMillis = sharedPreferences(LAST_TIME_OF_ACTION, 0L)

// current time given by the system
val currentTimeInMillis = System.getTimeInMillis()

// time difference in seconds
val timePassedInMillis = (currentTimeInMillis - lastTimeUserDidSmthInMillis) / 1000

if (timePassedInMillis > TIME_THRESHOLD) {
  doSomething()
} else {
  // not enough time has passed yet
}
```

Comment: `LAST_TIME_OF_ACTION` and `TIME_THRESHOLD`  are some constants you set

Comment: Or, use same approach but with the `Instant` and `Duration` *java.time* classes.